# Fill listview from array of objects

Tags: android

I need to show custom items on a list but after trying many different ways to solve the problem I'm still stuck with this error:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
> ComponentInfo{quinto3.et37.agendadeviajes/quinto3.et37.agendadeviajes.Principal}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
> cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Here is the principal activity

```
public class Principal extends Activity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;

    private ArrayAdapter<TipoDeViaje> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.agenda_principal);
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        View footer = ((LayoutInflater)     this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_add_button,     (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), false);
        lista.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
        llenarLista();
        registerForContextMenu(lista);
    }

    private void llenarLista() {
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        TipoDeViajeDAO tManager = new TipoDeViajeDAO(this);
        ArrayList<TipoDeViaje> tipoList = tManager.traerTodos(this);
        mAdapter = new AdapterTipoDeViaje(this,tipoList);
        lista.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void footerClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "pls", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EditTipoDeViaje.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        llenarLista();
    }
```

Here is my custom adapter

```
public class AdapterTipoDeViaje extends ArrayAdapter<TipoDeViaje> {
    public AdapterTipoDeViaje(Context context, ArrayList<TipoDeViaje> tipos) {
        super(context, 0, tipos);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        TipoDeViaje t = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_fila, parent,     false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView desdeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desde_text);
        TextView hastaText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hasta_text);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        desdeText.setText(t.getDesde().getNombre());
        hastaText.setText(t.getHasta().getNombre());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
```

And here is my lista_fila.xml (the layout I want to use for the row)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desde_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="desde"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hasta_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hasta"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/boton_agregar_registro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/boton_agregar_registro"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_viaje" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is agenda_principal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is footer_add_button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="7dip" >
    <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/footer_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="footerClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_button" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_footer_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the footer inflation.

Try this :

```
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer_add_button, lista, false);
lista.addFooterView(footer);
```

Comment: I'm getting thsi error now:
    The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type     LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, ListView,     null)

Comment: Oups sorry for the mistake ;) good to know you find the solution.